# How to change server response directory path into a URL in Android

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, api

Iam getting Url from api server resonse but i don't know wether should i mainpulate the format of the url given by the response or url given should 
be direct for download

this is the response i am getting

this is the link generated by api
**h:\root\home\ashaaban-001\www\LabRoot\Uploaded\04-Java-OOP-Basics.pdf**

[RESPONSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3V9zn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try appending it with the Google docs url and open it

```
"https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="
```

Comment: sadly it didn't work :3 , the problem is we don't know if that is done from the android side or the asp side